# Modify MapCruncher sample to make it generate tiles with GCS 1984 spatial reference

Tags: arcgis-engine

I want the MapCooker sample to generate tiles with a projected spatial reference of GCS WGS 1984.  I currently initialize it with a path to a layer with the NAD_1983_HARN_Adj_MN_Isanti_Feet coordinate system.   The sample is here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Multithreaded_MapCruncher/000100000mmm000000/

I already modified the sample to produce .pngs, by changing the StorageFormat to

```
cacheStorageInfo.StorageFormat = esriMapCacheStorageFormat.esriMapCacheStorageModeExploded;
```

Now I want to control the projected .pngs spatial reference.  Any idea how to do this?  I've been messing around with it for 2 hours with no luck.

I'm using ArcEngine 10 with C# and VS2010

Comment: Did you try setting the spatialreference of the map (i.e. dataframe) in the mxd to WGS 84?  Not sure, but you might need to set a geotransformation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with projections quite a bit and then I tried something obvious and it worked.

Load the target file.
Then change the function:    IMap GetMapFromDocument(string mapDocFullPath)

To this:

```
IMap GetMapFromDocument()
{
    IMap map = YourMapThatHasTargetLayerLoaded.activeView as IMap; 
    return map; 
}
```